# KTouring Recursive Code

Tags: c, recursion, chess

I can't seem to find why there are still some -1's left in the output. What should I implement to make it occupy all the spaces. I double checked the flow but I think the problem is when I call the function in main with position (0,0). But wouldn't the recursive function itself find an alternate solution if there is no solution on the position (0,0)
Help appreciated.

```
#define N 8
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int xMove[8] = {1,1,-1,-1,2,2,-2,-2};
int yMove[8] = {2,-2,2,-2,1,-1,1,-1};

int isSafe(int x, int y, int board[N][N])
{
     if(x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 && y < N && board[x][y] == -1)
         return 1;
     else
         return 0;
}

int SolveKT(int x, int y, int imove, int board[N][N])
{
    int next_x, next_y, i;

    if(imove == N * N)
        return 1;

    for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        next_x = x+xMove[i];
        next_y = y+yMove[i];

        if(isSafe(next_x,next_y,board))
        {
             board[next_x][next_y]=imove;

             if(SolveKT(next_x,next_y,++imove,board))
                 return 1;
             else
                 board[next_x][next_y]=-1;      
        }//close if
    }//close for

    return 0;
}//close SolveKT

int main()
{
    int i,j,res,cboard[N][N]={[0 ... N-1][0 ... N-1]=-1};
    res = SolveKT(0,0,0,cboard);

    if(res)
    { 
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
                printf("%d ",cboard[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}//close main
```

Comment: What is this: `[0 ... N-1][0 ... N-1]=-1`?  Is that C?

Comment: I think the OP just used it to make the initialization more clear to SO users. IMO memset() would be more appropriate....

Comment: It is a fairly heavy processing.

Comment: Probably should be `if(SolveKT(next_x,next_y,1+imove,board))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use `++imove`, you should use `imove+1`, because you shouldn't change the variable `imove` in the function.

But, this algorithm is very very slow, you should rethink about it.